# MissingMethodException from Async serialisation operation

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-4.5, async-await

I have written a small Async library wrapper to [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) v5.06 from NuGet and after updating a number of Telerik packages my UnitTests started to fail with a [MissingMethodException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception.aspx).

I have created a dummy non Async method which works so I am confused where the error lies.

**Project Target Platform**

.Net 4.5

x86 CPU

**Async Operation**

```
    public class JsonSerialiser : ISerialiser
    {

        [InjectionConstructor]
        public JsonSerialiser(IStringCompression streamCompressor, ILog logger)
        {
            if (streamCompressor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("streamCompressor");
            if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");

            XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            this.streamCompressor = streamCompressor;
            this.logger = logger;
        }


        public async Task<string> SerialiseAsync<T>(T serialseObject) where T : class
        {
            if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

            try
            {
                return await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(serialseObject);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
                throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Serialse The Object", ex);
            }
        }
   }
```

**Async Example**

Now this code was throw together just to test the basic serialisation where I step over the null checks in the class constructor.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Part> parts = new List<Part> { new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(IOpcController), ConcreteType = typeof(OpcController) },
                                                new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(ISerialiser), ConcreteType = typeof(JsonSerialiser) },
                                                new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(IStringCompression), ConcreteType = typeof(StringGZipCompression)}};

        string serialisedResult = string.Empty;
        JsonSerialiser serialiser = new JsonSerialiser(null, null);
        serialisedResult = await serialiser.SerialiseAsync<List<Part>>(parts);
    }
```

**Async Result**

This generation an MissingMethodException

[image]

```
Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.String> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(System.Object)'.

   at Helper.Core.Serialisation.Json.JsonSerialiser.<SerialiseAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Helper.Core.Serialisation.Json.JsonSerialiser.SerialiseAsync[T](T serialseObject)
   at OpcTester.Form1.<button1_Click>d__9.MoveNext() in c:\Users\phil.murray\Desktop\tmp\OpcTester\Form1.cs:line 44
```

**None Async operation**

Just to check if it was the asynchronous part of the method that was causing the problem I wrote a none asynchronous implementation.

```
public string Serialise<T>(T serialseObject) where T : class
{
    if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

    try
    {
        return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serialseObject);
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Serialse The Object", ex);
    }
}
```

**None Async Implementation**

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part> { new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(IOpcController), ConcreteType = typeof(OpcController) },
                                            new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(ISerialiser), ConcreteType = typeof(JsonSerialiser) },
                                            new Part() { AbstractType = typeof(IStringCompression), ConcreteType = typeof(StringGZipCompression)}};

    string serialisedResult = string.Empty;
    JsonSerialiser serialiser = new JsonSerialiser(null, null);
    serialisedResult = serialiser.Serialise<List<Part>>(parts);
}
```

**None Async Result**

The method completes and serialises the List to a string.

**Failed Test Example**

```
    Test Name:  SerialiserSerialiseObjectExists
    Test FullName:  Helper.Tests.SerialiserTests.SerialiserSerialiseObjectExists
    Test Source:    c:\Perforce\Development\SharedAPIs\Helper.Core\Helper.Tests\SerialiserTests.cs : line 38
    Test Outcome:   Failed
    Test Duration:  0:00:00.0116216

    Result Message: 
    Test method Helper.Tests.SerialiserTests.SerialiserSerialiseObjectExists threw exception: 
    System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.String> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(System.Object)'.
    Result StackTrace:  
    at Helper.Core.Serialisation.Json.JsonSerialiser.<SerialiseAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       a

t System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Helper.Core.Serialisation.Json.JsonSerialiser.SerialiseAsync[T](T serialseObject)
   at Helper.Tests.SerialiserTests.<SerialiserSerialiseObjectExists>d__3.MoveNext() in c:\Perforce\Development\SharedAPIs\Helper.Core\Helper.Tests\SerialiserTests.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

**Async Test without Json.Net**

Just for arguments sake I replaced the Json.Net call with a dummy Task and it worked so it looks like the problem is with calling Json.net using Await\Async. Strange as this was working and the version has not been updated.

```
public async Task<string> SerialiseAsync<T>(T serialseObject) where T : class
{
    if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

    try
    {
        //return await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(serialseObject);
        return await Task.Run(() => string.Empty);
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Serialse The Object", ex);
    }
}
```

**Question**

Now the asynchronous method UnitTests were previously working before I updated the Telerik controls suite and I did test the operation in a number of real world instances. I am not saying the Telerik update caused the problem as it may be a coincidence. A number of other asynchronous tests cases pass when testing other classes (not related to Json.Net).

Any idea what's wrong with the Async method and how to resolve the problem?

**Possible Resolution**

As I continued to investigate the problem it occurred to me that the problem may be in the Async call in the Json.Net library so I wrappered the none Async call in a Task, as below, which worked

```
    public async Task<string> SerialiseAsync<T>(T serialseObject) where T : class
    {
        if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

        try
        {
            //return await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(serialseObject);
            return await Task.Run<string>(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serialseObject));
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Serialse The Object", ex);
        }
    }
```

Out of interest I downloaded the source for Json.Net and checked out the JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync call and it was doing the same thing so I am again unsure of the underlying problem.

```
public static Task<string> SerializeObjectAsync(object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
{
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SerializeObject(value, formatting, settings));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Json.net?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output directory containing the assembly you are executing.
Inside Newtonsoft.Json.dll properties you will see that the description is "Json.Net Portable .Net 4.0" and this version doesn't provide SerializeObjectAsync (you may check the assembly using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)).

[image]

Replace the Json assembly by .Net 4.5 version and it should work.

Comment: The dll is the version from the net45 folder of the NuGet package. File Description - Json.Net ; File Version - 5.0.6.16206.

Comment: It looks like the assembly loaded in your AppDomain is not the net45 version. You might check which assembly is used maybe using fuslogvw or manually listing assemblies loaded in your AppDomain.